# Kendo UI - Text Color change went click Cancel

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Greeting,

I have a working demo here, almost similar with my situation.

[Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OBOxewib)

I successfully make the text color change to red when *Discontinued* column is *false* using **dataBound** function. But when I click on **Edit** then I click back on **Cancel** then text color is gone. So how can make sure if I click Cancel the text color still in **red**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the `Cancel` event as well. For example:

```
dataSource: dataSource,
  cancel: highlight,
  dataBound: highlight,

...

function highlight() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.view();

    $.each(data, function (i, row) {
      var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
      if (row.Discontinued == false) {
        $(element).addClass("red");
      }
    });
  }, 10);
}
```

The only downside with this solution is that there is this tiny timeout. I guess the `Cancel` event is fired before the form fields have been removed, although this is not explicetly mentioned in the documentation https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/cancel

Comment: It worked! well first time using kendo and i still need to explore more. btw thank you.

Comment: Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct or useful solution. Read more about accepting answers on https://stackoverflow.com/tour